# What's the Key Enumeration of Keys on top of Non-Numpad Number Keys?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I seem can't find the Key enumerations of some keys below. I also have read through this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx and still didn't find any (or maybe I missed it)

[image]

Questions :

1. What are the Key enumeration of the red-boxed keys in the picture above?
2. There's `Oemtilde` in the given link, any idea what key is that?

Thank you.

(My programming language is C# and I code in WPF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think there are seperate enums for these keys. These are `Key.D1 to Key.D0` and `Key.Oem3` (for tilda). You can identify which one was pressed by checking  `Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift` at any point in your code.

i.e if pressed key is `Key.D1` and `Keyboard.Modifiers` is `ModifierKeys.Shift` that means `'!'` was pressed

Comment: Just make sure you check modifier with `(e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift`, because there can be more than one modifier key pressed at once.

Comment: What's the difference if I check the modifiers using, for example, `if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)||Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)){//Code}`? Is it just for code simplification only?

Answer (score 0):

How about to run application, press key on keyboard and check the value of KeyEventArgs.Key?

```
private void MainWindow_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Key);
}
```

Shows Oem3 for tilda.

Comment: It always detect `LeftShift + Something`, not the `Key` name itself. Or maybe that's how we need to access it, since it has no particular name?